# Contour Lines Raster Extraction

Tags: qgis, raster, contour, heat-map, mapbox

I've been playing with Mapbox's blog post about [converting heat maps to contour lines](http://mapbox.com/blog/contour-lines-density-mapping/), and I'm stuck at the extraction part of this process.

I used the CSV plugin to create a vector layer of points, then a heat map raster layer based on that, but I can't seem to be able to see the contour lines based on that raster layer after that. When I looked at the properties and selected categorized, it didn't seem to have any symbols listed.

I'm guessing this is probably some kind of type error since I had to create the raster layer based off of map units and not meters, but I don't know how to correct it. What am I missing?

Here's a screenshot. It's a map of racially charged geographic locations based on their name. The main difference being that I've stripped any instances of Arroyo Negro, but left in more explicit cases.

[image: qgis screenshot]

Comment: How did you create the contour lines? Did you use the gdal tool in the "Raster->Extraction" menu?

Comment: @Micha Yes I did. Was that a bad thing?

Comment: No, that's the correct procedure. What did not work as you expected? What do you mean "didn't seem to have any symbols listed" ??

Comment: @Micha I'm assuming that when I went to layer properties and switched to categories that there would be a table of symbols, values, and lables. Right now it's just empty.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot so we don't have to guess what's going on? which attribute did you chose for categorization?

Comment: @underdark you got it. elev

Comment: Did you try hitting classify button? How does the attribute table look like?

Comment: You may have better results using kriging or interpolation.

Comment: Yup @underdark and still no luck. I'm going to try and find a way to get a hold of the guy at Mapbox. I'm not too familiar with kriging or interpolation, though.

Comment: Any chance of sharing a data sample?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. What do you mean by "type error with the CRS" and how exactly did you solve it ? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey dokey. After the holiday weekend I figured it out.

It was basically a type error with the CRS. Although it's not explicitly stated, I got in touch with MapBox and found out they were working in Google Mercator. It's also a perfectly acceptable CRS to use when you eventually have to import the .shp file into MapBox/Tile Mill.